# MATLAB 2013a command line GUI error

Tags: matlab

I use MATLAB on the command line: `matlab -nodesktop`

My environment:

> MATLAB Version: 8.1.0.604 (R2013a)
>
> Operating System: Mac OS X Version: 10.8.5 Build: 12F37
>
> Java Version: Java 1.6.0_51-b11-457-11M4509 with Apple Inc. Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM mixed mode

Everything works fine with the computation and plots.

However, when I call the editor GUI via `edit` (or `doc`), I see lots of log messages like the following:

> 2013-09-26 15:42:09.010 MATLAB_maci64[92855:f07] *** CPerformer:
>   ignoring exception '*** -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object
>   cannot be nil' raised during perform of selector '_nativeGetTypes:' on
>   target '' with args '( )'

The MATLAB editor itself works fine, but the error log messages in the command line are annoying. Does anybody know how to resolve the error or suppress the error message?

Comment: I have had similar problems when Java was not updated, or when a Java update caused some kind of conflict with Matlab.